# 'id_token_hint' in RP Initiated Logout

Tags: java, openid-connect

I'm working with the spec 'https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPLogout' to implement the feature, RP initiated logout. What I need to know is actually what is meant by 'id_token_hint' here. Is it same as the client ID or is it authorization code which we receive from the OP after login to it. Otherwise what is the 'id_token_hint' mentioned in the spec. Any explanation is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `id_token_hint` parameter is the actual ID Token that was received earlier from the OpenID Connect Provider. As the spec says:

> This is used as an indication of the identity of the End-User that the
>   RP is requesting be logged out by the OP.

It would prevent attackers from clickjacking and logging out users from their accounts because only the real RP can present the valid ID Token for the user (although the OP should ask for confirmation before actually logging the user out).

Comment: Does it means that I have to store id_token during after authentication flow finished until logout initiated. Or can I erquest it for example from userInfo endpoint?
Also specs https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html
saying that user must get a confirmation dialog if id_token_hint was not provided, so theoretically id_token_hint parameter is not required. Right?